# AxisTime to Java Time

Tags: java, time

Im trying to convert an axis.types.Time into sql.Time like this:

```
    org.apache.axis.types.Time axisTime = (org.apache.axis.types.Time) valore;
    Calendar calendarTime = axisTime.getAsCalendar();
    java.sql.Time jsqlT = java.sql.Time.valueOf( cal.get(cal.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" +  cal.get(cal.MINUTE) + ":" + cal.get(cal.SECOND) );
```

but i have one hour of difference between the conversion. Is this daylight-related? How can i fix that?

(OUTPUT:
AXIS TIME: `20:45:00.000Z`

CALENDAR : `java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=-62167403700000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Berlin",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=143,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Berlin,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=0,YEAR=2,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=1,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=31,DAY_OF_YEAR=365,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=5,AM_PM=1,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=21,MINUTE=45,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=0]`

SQLTIME `21:45:00`

Edit: i solved that by working with strings... But this axis-date/time object aren't very friendly with daylight and timezones, the DateTime object was trouble was even worse (again, I forced the solution ignoring GMT/Daylights and working with strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
org.apache.axis.types.Time axisTime = (org.apache.axis.types.Time) valore;
Calendar calendarTime = axisTime.getAsCalendar();
java.sql.Time jsqlT = new java.sql.Time(calendarTime.getTimeInMillis());
```

That way you shouldn't have issues with the daylight savings time change.